# What's is <details> in react?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm reading: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

There is a link to an example: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010

There is a tag "details" at line 22 in that example. What's it? Where is the doc about it?

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // Catch errors in any components below and re-render with error message
    this.setState({
      error: error,
      errorInfo: errorInfo
    })
    // You can also log error messages to an error reporting service here
  }

  render() {
  if (this.state.errorInfo) {
    // Error path
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Something went wrong.</h2>
        <details style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
          {this.state.error && this.state.error.toString()}
          <br />
          {this.state.errorInfo.componentStack}
        </details>
      </div>
    );
  }
  // Normally, just render children
  return this.props.children;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<details>` is the normal HTML `details`-tag.

You can read more about the tag on the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details).

> The **HTML Details Element (`<details>`)** creates a disclosure widget in which information is visible only when the widget is toggled into an "open" state. A summary or label can be provided using the [`<summary>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) element.
>
> A disclosure widget is typically presented onscreen using a small triangle which rotates (or twists) to indicate open/closed status, with a label next to the triangle. If the first child of the `<details>` element is a `<summary>`, the contents of the `<summary>` element are used as the label for the disclosure widget.

Answer (score 2):

That is a html tag
You can see docs: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp

Answer (score 0):

In React,  can be used like this if you want to custom define the open state yourself:

```js
<details
  onClick={(e: any) => {
    // prevent default on the Click Event to stop it conflicting
    e.preventDefault()
  }} {...open ?{open: true}: {}}>
          <summary onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>Click me</summary>
  {'Shown/Hidden content goes here'}
</details>
```

It is important to use `{...open ? {open: true}: {}}` because open="false" evaluates to open=true.